# maintain terraform azure state file in one subscription and deploy to multiple cloud subscriptions

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

I need to store my terraform state file in a single azure storage account and deploy it to multiple cloud subscriptions(china and public cloud)..
I have my backend configured as below:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=2.78.0"
    }
  }
  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name = "Terraform-rg"
    storage_account_name = "terraformstate"
    container_name = "tfstate"
    subscription_id = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
    key = "prod"
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}


provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  alias           = "sub2"
  subscription_id = "xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx"
  client_id       = "xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx"
  client_secret   = var.client_secret
  tenant_id       = "xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

However, when I am trying to terraform init with this approach, I am getting the below error:

```
Failed to get configured named states: Error retrieving keys for Storage Account "terraformstate": storage.AccountsClient#ListKeys: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=404 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=404 Code="SubscriptionNotFound" Message="The subscription 'xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx' could not be found."
```

I was wondering if it is even possible to do this?
I also have a script to terraform init and terraform plan which would switch the cloud based on env..
"az cloud set --name AzureChinaCloud" for china and for non china "az cloud set --name AzureCloud"
The storage account subscription is in AzureCloud.. How do I authorise to write the state file for AzureChinaCloud in AzureCloud?
Is this approach even possible?

Comment: Hello @pk_dhruv, another script won't be required for setting the cloud , you can directly add a environment parameter in the provider blocks. you can refer this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69344748/azure-managed-identity-and-terraform-not-working-in-azureusgoverment/69356239#69356239)

Comment: and for the subscription not found error can you try the above suggestion first and then perform a `terraform init` . as you have set the could from cli it might be creating problem .

Comment: Please let me know if the above resolves the issue

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT.. Yes.. The link which you mentioned did the trick.. I missed adding the environment and that was causing the issue.. AFter I added the env, things started working as expected..
Thank you for the help!!

Comment: cool.. Glad to be of help will post the same as answer.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment section, The issue in your code is you are missing `Environment` parameter in the `provider` block . As you were manually setting the cloud environment so, the code was not able to find the Subscription in the Backend Configuration which is in public cloud .

So, the solution will be setting the parameter in the code like below and not manually using `az CLI` :

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=2.78.0"
    }
  }
  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name = "Terraform-rg"
    storage_account_name = "terraformstate"
    container_name = "tfstate"
    subscription_id = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
    key = "prod"
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}


provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  alias           = "USGovernment"
  subscription_id = "xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx"
  client_id       = "xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx"
  client_secret   = var.client_secret
  tenant_id       = "xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx"
  environment     = "usgovernment"
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  alias           = "China"
  subscription_id = "xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx"
  client_id       = "xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx"
  client_secret   = var.client_secret
  tenant_id       = "xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx"
  environment     = "china"
}
```

**Reference:**

[Docs overview | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs#argument-reference)

[SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69344748/azure-managed-identity-and-terraform-not-working-in-azureusgoverment/69356239#69356239)